# Is there a polynomial-time algorithm to check if a signed graph contains an odd-K5 minor?

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, graph-theory, algorithms, graph-minors

I suspect this exists, if anyone has a reference please that would be very helpful.

By signed graph, I mean each edge is designated either odd or even (e.g. as in Guenin's result for weakly bipartite graphs).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes.  This result is contained in my PhD thesis, which is available [here](https://uwspace.uwaterloo.ca/bitstream/handle/10012/4716/huynh_tony.pdf?sequence=1&isAllowed=y) (see Theorem 1.1.10).  We prove that for any finite abelian group $\Gamma$ and fixed $\Gamma$-labeled graph $H$, there is a polynomial time algorithm to determine if an input $\Gamma$-labelled graph $G$ contains an $H$-minor.  The case you are interested in is $\Gamma=\mathbb{Z} / 2 \mathbb{Z}$ and $H$ equals odd-$K_5$.  For signed graphs, this result was also obtained independently by [Kawarabayashi, Reed, and Wollan](http://wwwusers.di.uniroma1.it/~wollan/PUBS/parity_minors_web.pdf) (although I am not sure that a journal version is available yet).

Comment: It is "Kawarabayashi", not "Kawawarabayashi".

Comment: @mathlove Thanks for spotting that typo.  It has been edited.

Comment: @TonyHuynh, many thanks for your help! Do you know if there's some kind of generalization of Guenin's result (characterizing weakly bipartite signed graphs) to the more general setting you've looked at, with $\Gamma$-labeled graphs?